# extend parent in scala using field constants

Tags: java, scala

I would like to extend a parent in scala with the aid of static final fields.
The parent class has no no-argument constructor.

The code i would use in Java is:

```
class Child extends Parent{
    public static final String param = "I_AM_NEEDED";

    Child(){
        super(param);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to do it in scala, for example like

```
class Child( val param:String = "I_AM_NEEDED" ) extends Parent(param){
    //code here
}
```

so that you have a field which you can't change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Scala, static fields are kept on an `object` and not a `class`.  So to replicate the Java behavior in Scala, you should create a `Child` companion object that has the `param` stored.  Then you can just pass it to the `Parent` constructor:

```
class Parent(val s: String)

class Child() extends Parent(Child.param)

object Child {
  val param = "I_AM_NEEDED"
}
```